# Wordpress Company address variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, footer

Some dude helped me out once bulding a wordpress site. The company has since moved to another location and now our address info around the site is wrong. In the footer and other places there's a echo $address but I have no idea where that variable is stored or where I can edit it. The WP dashboard doesn't seem to have any answers, It's not hard coded and searching thru the DB doesn't help me much. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Did you try looking in the header.php file? Without direct access to the code, it will be hard to tell. Your best bet is to download the website and use a program like notepad++ to search through all the files to look for `$address`to see where it is being set.

Comment: I found this in the footer.php - $address = get_field('address', $home_page_id) And I don't know where to go from here. BTW as you might have figured out, I am not a developer ;)

Comment: Do you have a plugin called advanced custom fields installed?

Comment: Yes... is the answer hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, if you disable it does the address disappear?

Comment: Yup... half the site disappeared

Comment: haha woops... Open the custom fields page from the dashboard and look through that. It should be in there.

Comment: Nothing there. He sure hid it well

Comment: Check the tables in the database related to the advanced custom fields plugin, it should be there then.

Comment: Can't find anything. I also search for the actual address in the DB, but didn't find it. To me that would suggest hard code, but I also search the entire project and nothing there. This is gettin' weird.

Comment: If get_field() is being used I am 100% sure that it will be in the database.

Comment: Wait... there's multiple hits in wp_postmeta. Guess I overlooked it before. Doesn't help me much tho

Comment: If you change them does it change the address on the site?

Comment: Perhaps. But there's like over 100 of them. Maybe it's just time for me to hardcode them instead

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "address", you mean physical address and not domain, I'd recommend that you right click on the element (if you're using Chrome or Firefox, that is) and select the "Inspect Element" option. That will give you insight on the classname or id of the element you're trying to modify. Then you can inspect your code for that element to find out how it's generated.

If it's hardcoded, you can change it in the WordPress admin panel by clicking on the Appearance->Editor menu item and modifying that bit of code. Otherwise, the code should give you some kind of hint as to where it can otherwise be modified.